# What trait tells the compiler that `T` is simple type with implicit copy?

Tags: generics, rust

I intend to use the following struct with simple numeric types like `i32`, `usize`, but in the implementation of the `contains()` method, Rust forces me to use `Clone` instead of an implicit copy ("cannot move out of borrowed content").

I did not find any trait that would tell the compiler that `T` is simple type with implicit copy. Can I count on the compiler that the `clone()` call will be discarded for numeric types, without any performance hit?

```
pub struct Rect<T> {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
    pub w: T,
    pub h: T,
}

impl<T> Rect<T> where T: PartialOrd + Add<T, Output=T> + Clone {
    pub fn contains(&self, x: T, y: T) -> bool {
        x >= self.x && y >= self.y
            && x < self.x.clone() + self.w.clone()
            && y < self.y.clone() + self.h.clone()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait to indicate that a type has copy semantics (instead of move semantics).

```
impl<T> Rect<T> where T: PartialOrd + Add<T, Output=T> + Copy {
    pub fn contains(&self, x: T, y: T) -> bool {
        x >= self.x && y >= self.y
            && x < self.x + self.w
            && y < self.y + self.h
    }
}
```

> Can I count on the compiler that the `clone()` call will be discarded for numeric types, without any performance hit?

We hope that the compiler do this optimization, but there are no guarantees (thanks @DK).

There is an [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1521-copy-clone-semantics.md) to formalize the semantics of `clone` for `Copy` types. The RFC start with the following:

> It's generally been an unspoken rule of Rust that a clone of a `Copy` type is equivalent to a `memcpy` of that type

Comment: AFAIK, what you said about `clone` is not true.  There was an RFC that required that they have the same effect if they're both implemented, but there's nothing that says the compiler *has* to replace the call to `clone` with a bit copy.  Ideally, the optimiser will take care of that, but again, that's not *guaranteed*.